# How to navigate in const function [react native]

Tags: react-native

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I add props to this function in order to navigate

```
const usersRef = firestore().collection('Users');

 //const  signIn  = React.useContext(AuthContext);
 const  { signIn }  = React.useContext(AuthContext);


const CreateUser = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    let response = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    if (response) {
      console.log( "?", response)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message)
  }
 usersRef.add({
      // Name: this.state.Name,
       Email: email
      })
       navigation.navigate("SignIn")
}

export function RegisterScreen({navigation}) {
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
  
    const { register } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    const {container, txtInput} = styles;
  
    return (
      <View style={container}>
        <Text>Reg</Text>
        <TextInput 
          placeholder="email"
          value={email}
          onChangeText={setEmail}
          style={txtInput}
        />
        <TextInput 
          placeholder="Password"
          value={password}
          onChangeText={setPassword}
          secureTextEntry
          style={txtInput}
        />
       
        <Button title="Register" onPress={() => {
          // navigation.navigate('signIn')
          //register(email,password)
          CreateUser(email,password)
            
            }} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

2. I want to make it logged in after the registration is complete, so far as my understanding I need to get it to SignIn function of my AuthContext

I have `const  signIn  = React.useContext(AuthContext);`

and I try to do `signIn(email,password)` after or before the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

please try this, where did you put it CreateUser

```
const  { signIn }  = React.useContext(AuthContext);
const data = {
  username: state.username,
  password: state.password
}
signIn(data)
```

App.js

it will switch automatically

```
{userToken ? 
<RootStack.Navigator>
  <RootStack.screen />
</RootStack.Navigator> :
<RootStack.Navigator>
  <RootStack.screen />
</RootStack.Navigator>}
```

You can change routes by doing this

```
const CreateUser = async (data,navigation) => {
  try {
    let response = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    if (response) {
      console.log("test")
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message)
  }
 usersRef.add({
      // Name: this.state.Name,
       Email: email
      })
       navigation.navigate("SignIn")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, may I show you the full code? cause I passed the arguments after button press and I dont really know how to pass it within that const data

Comment: could you please assist me with how to pass the email and password to that const data?
I got the values from user input update hook

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by changing registration to class then I was able to use navigation and using constructor props.
The only problem is that the auth context doesnt seem to support class. so I navigate after registration to signIn that remained as function so there Im able to use the authContext SignIn

If someone want to help me and tell me if its possible to manage it on class instead of function it would be greatful.